# Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having an issue with my JS code.

I keep getting the following error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

JS Code:

```js
    const weatherIcon = document.getElementById('weather-icon');

    const icon = document.createElement('img');
    icon.setAttribute('id', 'icon');
    icon.src = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/50n.png";
    console.log(icon);
    weatherIcon.appendChild(icon);    //error is on this line
```

```html
<div id="weather-data">
          <div id="weather-icon">
              
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: work perfectly for me

Comment: This means `weatherIcon` is failing to find the element with ID 'weather-icon'. Probably you're running this code before the DOM has loaded.

Comment: `#weather-icon` doesn't exist when your JS is executing. `document.getElementById("weather-icon")` is returning `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your script is executing before the DOM fully loaded. Try with [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). This will ensure that the code inside will be executed only after the DOM is fully loaded.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  const weatherIcon = document.getElementById('weather-icon');

  const icon = document.createElement('img');
  icon.setAttribute('id', 'icon');
  icon.src = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/50n.png";
  console.log(icon);
  weatherIcon.appendChild(icon);
});
```

```html
<div id="weather-data">
  <div id="weather-icon"></div>
</div>
```